# Does the Object spread syntax never throw an error?

Tags: javascript, spread-syntax, ecmascript-2018

I noticed that the Object Spread syntax is extremely permissive on what kinds of values it can accept:

```js
console.log({ ...true });
console.log({ ...false });
console.log({ ...0 });
console.log({ ...42 });
console.log({ ...-1 });
console.log({ ...NaN });
console.log({ ...'batman' });
console.log({ .../\w+[0-9a-fA-F]?/ });
console.log({ ...['foo', 'bar', 42] });
console.log({ ...undefined });
console.log({ ...false });
console.log({ ...Symbol('hmm') });
console.log({ ...Promise.resolve('resolved') });
console.log({ ...Promise.reject('rejected') });
```

Is there a type, class, or value that is invalid (i.e. throws any kind of error) when spread inside an object literal? Not counting uncaught rejected promises, of course.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there is no expression that is invalid when spread inside an object literal, provided of course that the evaluation of that expression itself does not throw an error.

We can see that this is true from the ECMAScript specification:

At [12.2.6 Object Initializer](https://262.ecma-international.org/11.0/#sec-object-initializer), we find the syntax definition for the object literal spread syntax:

> *PropertyDefinition*:
> `...` *AssignmentExpression*<sub>[+In, ?Yield, ?Await]</sub>

An *AssignmentExpression* represents all possible expressions (including assignments), except for the comma operator, which practically means that you need to use parentheses if you want a comma to be interpreted as the comma operator instead of the object literal's comma separator (See [12.15 Assignment Operators](https://262.ecma-international.org/11.0/#sec-assignment-operators) and [12.16 Comma Operator](https://262.ecma-international.org/11.0/#sec-comma-operator)).

The evaluation procedure is specified in [12.2.6.8 Runtime Semantics: PropertyDefinitionEvaluation](https://262.ecma-international.org/11.0/#sec-object-initializer-runtime-semantics-propertydefinitionevaluation):

> *PropertyDefinition*:`...`*AssignmentExpression*
>
> 1. Let *exprValue* be the result of evaluating *AssignmentExpression*.
> 2. Let *fromValue* be ? GetValue(*exprValue*).
> 3. Let *excludedNames* be a new empty List.
> 4. Return ? CopyDataProperties(*object*, *fromValue*, *excludedNames*).

We assumed that the expression itself would not throw during evaluation, which means that the above GetValue procedure will succeed without error. We then can check what CopyDataProperties does in [7.3.25 CopyDataProperties](https://262.ecma-international.org/11.0/#sec-copydataproperties). The important steps are:

> 3. If *source* is `undefined` or `null`, return *target*.
> 4. Let *from* be ! ToObject(*source*).

Now ToObject would throw when *source* is either `null` or `undefined`, but those two cases were already treated (as a no-operation) in the preceding step. All other primitive values are boxed into a wrapper object (See [7.1.18 ToObject](https://262.ecma-international.org/11.0/#sec-toobject)).

Finally, CopyDataProperties has one more step that could throw:

> 6. c. 2. ii. Perform ! CreateDataPropertyOrThrow(*target*, *nextKey*, *propValue*).

But that can only throw when the property to be set already exists and is not configurable, or the target object is not extensible (See [7.3.7 CreateDataPropertyOrThrow](https://262.ecma-international.org/11.0/#sec-createdatapropertyorthrow) and [7.3.5 CreateDataProperty](https://262.ecma-international.org/11.0/#sec-createdataproperty)). But such conditions do not occur in an object literal. They could occur in a larger evaluation where an object is extended, but such errors have nothing to do with spread syntax *specifically*.